# A countable subset of R without isolated points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is there a countable subset of $\mathbb{R},$ which doesn't have any isolated points?

It is an easy consequence of the Baire Category theorem that any closed countable set of reals has an isolated point. I am just wondering, if we can drop the condition about the set being closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $\Bbb Q$?  I don't think it has any isolated points.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you.

Comment: In fact all countable subsets without isolated points in a metric space are homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. So it's the only example, really.

Comment: That was the exactly the question I was about to ask next. How can we prove this?